# Create a PDF with charts, but not the background data, via Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, export-to-pdf

I'm trying to translate **multiple tabs with charts in a Gsheet workbook to PDF**.

Challenges:

- there are charts and I do not want to include the background numbers into the PDF. How to avoid it?
- I need multiple pages of PDF -- how to define the page breaks via script?

I checked a bunch of answers on Stack Overflow, Google, [GitHub](https://gist.github.com/ixhd/3660885), and so far it seems that I need to create a new sheet with only the relevant data. However, then the charts don't work as they loose connection.

Comment: Ask only 1 question: charts without background data and set page breaks are 2 unrelated questions and should not be in the same question. It is not sufficient to say "i checked a bunch of answers on Stack Overflow" and then **not link them**. How will we know that you have already reviewed a duplicate we will otherwise refer you to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying multiple suggestions, I came up with a reasonable workaround:

- Hide all the tabs that are irrelevant
- format the tabs so that the automatic page break is good enough: for an empty sheet, 1 page is 53 lines

Once that is set up, PDF can be sent using this code

```
  var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById('your file id').getAs("application/pdf").getBytes();

  var attach = {fileName:'Test stats PDF.pdf',content:pdf, mimeType:'application/pdf'};

 MailApp.sendEmail('email@gmail.com', 'subject', 'text', {attachments:[attach]});
```